# C# how to execute code before Thread.Sleep()?

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

```cs
    void SpaceBarUpdate() {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && timerStart == 0)   //if the timer isn't initialized and spacebar pressed
        {
            //txt.color = Color.red;

            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sleep started");
            Thread.Sleep(550);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sleep ended");


            if (Input.GetKey("space"))
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Space down");

                // txt.color = Color.green;
                txt.text = "READY";

                //timerStart = 1;
            }

        }
    }
```

The output of this code is intended to be as follows, if the spacebar is pressed: (without the 
color formatting)

```
Sleep started
# delay of 550ms
Sleep ended
```

and then if the spacebar is still held down,

```
Space down
```

However, upon tapping the spacebar once, it outputs nothing for 550ms and then outputs this all at once: (again without the color formatting)

```
Sleep Started
Sleep ended
Space down
```

How do I get the "Sleep started" message to occur *before* the thread sleeps, and why is it progressing with the second if statement when I don't have the spacebar held down?

Comment: Can you share what the purpose of the sleep is? I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but having an event handler for the key press might be a better choice than using a timer and a sleep.

Comment: @DougDawson the end goal is that the spacebar must be held for 550ms in order for a timer to be started (which is defined elsewhere in the function). It's supposed to emulate the cstimer.net website

Comment: I suppose this is because `UnityEngine.Debug.Log` is async, so it actually executed **before** `Thread.Sleep(550)`, but log `Sleep started` to console some nanoseconds after this call. But as your main thread is sleeping - you will see this log message only when you wake up. Anyway, `Thread.Sleep()` is some-kind-of-code-smell in UI applications.

Comment: @vasily.sib I see... is there any way to get around this? Because the eventual goal is not to make a console line, but rather change the color of the text before it sleeps so that text is red when the spacebar is initially pressed, then after 550ms if it is still pressed the text will turn green.

Comment: You may use `async / await` for this `UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sleep started"); await Task.Delay(550); UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sleep ended");`. Start your reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Using `Sleep` definitely isn't the way to achieve that end goal. You'll need to record the time that spacebar was initially pressed, and keep track of the spacebar state. Then if the spacebar is still down, and the time difference between now and initial press is more than the required delay, do your action.

Comment: @Herohtar I'm frankly astonished I didn't realize that sooner. I used a stopwatch and it works perfectly now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because the function `.Sleep()` pauses your program. Nothing is interpreted during that sleep time. If you want to be able to stop it, you must use an asynchrone method which is more advanced programming. You can read more about it in multiple sources online to learn.

Comment: I tried using an asynchronous method but it didn't wait at all, and just kept going without delay